# a problem related to inverse function theorem

Tags: real-analysis, multivariable-calculus

This problem is from Advanced Calculus 3rd by R. Buck.

Let $D$ be the unit disk, $x^2+y^2\leq1$. Consider a transformation $T$ of class $C^1$ on an open set containing $D$,

$$
T:\begin{cases}
u=f(x,y),\\
v=g(x,y),
\end{cases}
$$

whose Jacobian is never $0$ in $D$. Suppose that $T$ is near the identity map in the sense that $|T(p)-p|\leq\frac{1}{3}$ for all $p\in D$. Prove that there is a point $p_0$ with $T(p_0)=(0,0)^T$.

Thanks a lot.

Update: I have figured it out. Seems the problem does not involve too much "inverse function theorem". At first, I have no clue at all. Here is the idea.

Define a function $\varphi(p)=\|T(p)\|_2^2$. $\varphi(p)$ is in fact the distance function between $T(p)$ and $(0,0)^T$. Then we need to show $\min_{p\in D}\varphi(p)=0$. If this is true, then the claim is proved. Next, we show $p^*=\arg\min_{p\in D}\varphi(p)$ is an interior point of $D$. Then we can use the Fermat's condition and this gives $T(p^*)=0$ which completes the proof.

I deeply appreciate if someone can provide me examples of interesting applications of inverse/implicit function theorems.

Comment: Your question is phrased as an isolated problem, without any further information or context. This does not match [many users' quality standards](http://goo.gl/mLWc8), so it may attract downvotes, or be (temporarily) closed. To prevent that, please [edit] the question. [This](http://goo.gl/xQWVb) will help you recognise and resolve the issues. Concretely: please provide context, and include your work and thoughts on the problem. These changes can help in formulating more appropriate answers.